# Fastest way to find and address in a dataframe or other data structure

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 large excel files(300k and 500k).  Both files have information about addresses.

I need to load them into memory and then cycle through the 500k file and check if the address exists in the 300k file. If it does or doesn't I have to modify certain parts of the address or do something else and produce another excel file.

I am looking for the fastest way to find an address by matching civic,street,streettype,streetdirection and town in the 300k file.

Currently I am using:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    dfexists = dfsmall.loc[(dfsmall['civic'] == df.loc[i,'civic']) & (dfsmall['street'] == df.loc[i,'street']) & (dfsmall['streettype'] == df.loc[i,'streettype']) & (dfsmall['streetdirection'] == df.loc[i,'streetdirection']) & (dfsmall['town'] == df.loc[i,'town'])]

#if dfexists has a matching row do something with that row, if not do something else
```

This is very slow and I am looking for ways to speed it up.

Ive tried other methods such as masks with no luck, this is the fastest way I have found so far

ISSUES:
I have to cycle line by line so I cannot just do a dataframe compare therefore I need to know the fastest way to get rows from a dataframe or another container based on multiple columns matching given values.

Thanks

Comment: you could probably create a multi-index out of all of the columns you care about and do an inner join

Comment: How about creating a set of tuples for the 300k file and then check one by one for the 500k file? Checking a value in a set is O(1). So, it should speed up lookup quite a bit.

Comment: From what I read creating tuples is faster but accessing lists are faster so would the 300k one as a list be faster looping through to check each line be faster than df.loc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the columns you identified as keys, you can create sets of tuples consisting of values from the key columns for each dataframe  and do an intersection to find the common keys and set difference to find the delta.

You can also create a dictionary mapping keys back to row indices in the dataframe.

Checking set membership is O(1) so doing an intersection or difference is O(N). Looking up a value in a dictionary is O(1), so mapping back to indices is O(N). So this whole process is O(N).

Once you have the indices, you can do a loop or do vectorized operations to effect the changes you need for the two cases (common vs delta). You didn't provide many details on what those are, so the example code below uses fake do_something() functions as placeholders. If your operations are very simple, the complexity of vectorization may not be worth it since we are already doing O(N) at the python level. Vectorization is asymptotically the same at O(N) but without python overhead (factor of 1000 times faster or so).

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
#df_500k and df_300k provided
columns = ['civic','street','streettype','streetdirection','town']


list_500k = [tuple(row) for row in df_500k[columns].values.tolist()]
index_map_500k = dict(zip(list_500k,df_500k.index))

set_500k = set(list_500k)
del list_500k
set_300k = set(tuple(row) for row in df_300k[columns].values.tolist())


#edit: maybe this loop makes it more clear that one address is being processed at a time
for row_index, address_key in index_map_500k.items():
    if address_key in set_300k:
        #address is in both files
        df_row = df_500k.iloc[row_index,:]
        #do whatever you want in this case
    else:
        #address is not in the 300k file
        df_row = df_500k.iloc[row_index,:]
        #do whatever you want in this case
```

As mentioned above, as an alternative to the last loop, you can take a vectorized approach depending on how complicated or simple your processing is and whether it is expected to be a worse bottleneck than the set/dict operations above that are collectively O(N) with python overhead.

```py
indices_in_common = np.array([index_map_500k[key] for key in (set_500k & set_300k])
do_something_vectorized(df_500k,indices_in_common)

indices_delta = np.array([index_map_500k[key] for key in (set_500k - set_300k])
do_something_else_vectorized(df_500k,indices_delta)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unless im mistaken I do not believe this solves my question as I only need to find 1 address at a time and process it. Depending on processing I may look for that address again by changing the parameters slightly etc

Comment: @Pearl I believe this does solve your question. It divides every address in the 500k file into two piles - those that are in common with 300k and those that are not. It then processes each address one at a time, like you are asking. If you need to look for that address again you can look up the address by its key. I think you are saying you can't do a vectorized approach, which is fine - I listed that as an optional alternative anyway.

Comment: @Pearl This is an efficient way to process each thing one at a time. You can look up any row by address in O(1) and check if that address is present in the other file in O(1). The actual loop might look different depending on what you want to do. I can't help you with that because you haven't said what you want to do with each row.

Comment: @Pearl seems I have failed to convince you. I edited the last part of the example above to put it in a format that hopefully better illustrates how this is processing one address at a time and gives you flexibility to look up the row of the dataframe quickly and check whether the address is present in the 300k file or not.

Comment: Sorry I was away. I just tested this and it is very fast however it pulls in unique lines.  So for instance if I am just verifying the town and there are numerous addresses with the same town, it only verifies it once. In my dataset I will have numerous lines with the same address but will need other info from the line for the #do what you want area if this makes sense?

Comment: @Pearl It will key things uniquely by the columns identified in the columns variable I have which includes (civic,street,streettype, streetdirection,town) based on your post. This unique keying is what makes lookups fast. Are you saying that there could be multiple rows in the file that have identical values to each other for all of those columns? Or are you saying you changed it to only key off of town and removed the other columns? The columns variable should be left with a collection of columns that uniquely identifies each row. Verifying subsets can be done in the loop.

Comment: yes there will be multiple entries of the same address that need to be gone through 1X1 in the 500k file.  The 300k file is unique addresses.  Im looking at turning the 500k to a list, looping that, and checking the key in the 300k. This should speed it up?

Comment: @Pearl do you need to have fast lookup in the 500k file for an arbitrary address? If not then yes a list works fine. If so, then can modify the dictionary to map addresses to a set of indices instead of a single one.

Comment: no I do not need any lookup in the 500k. I have to check every address in the 500k to see if its in the 300k. If it is do something with the address, if not, possibly modify the paramaters and check it again in the 300k.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance.  I created the 500k list without the indexes and cycled that list and just created the key from the column(s) in the row  and checked vs the set_300k for the key.  For the subset of data I am using dfs took 625s old way and this takes .67s. HUGE. thanks:)